# IgniteQueue in Apache Ignite.NET

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ignite

We are using Ignite.NET and don't have option to use Ignite Java API (team skills, technology affinity etc). We are looking to create a queuing mechanism so that we could process messages in distributed fashion. I found IgniteQueue data structure to be most suitable but it doesn't seem to be available in ignite.net could someone please suggest a solution to the scenario. Multiple producers queue a unique work item to be processed reliably by only 1 consumer at a time.

E.g. there are P1,P2 producers (on different machines) they generate T1,T2,T3 on the queue and we have C1,C2,C3 consumers (on different machines) now T1 should be processed by ONLY 1 from C1,C2,C3 and so on for T2,T3 should also similarly be processed only once by 1 consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IgniteQueue is built on top of Ignite Cache, so yes, you can replicate the same functionality in .NET:

1. Create a cache
2. Use [Continuous Query](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/continuous-queries) as a consumer, call ICache.Remove to ensure that every item is processed only once
3. Add data to cache on producers with [Data Streamers](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/data-streamers) or just use `ICache.Put` / `PutAll`

Below is the code for continuous query listener:

```
class CacheEventListener<TK, TV> : ICacheEntryEventListener<TK, TV>
{
    private readonly string _cacheName;

    [InstanceResource]  // Injected automatically.
    private readonly IIgnite _ignite = null;

    private ICache<TK, TV> _cache;

    public CacheEventListener(string cacheName)
    {
        _cacheName = cacheName;
    }

    public void OnEvent(IEnumerable<ICacheEntryEvent<TK, TV>> events)
    {
        _cache = _cache ?? _ignite.GetCache<TK, TV>(_cacheName);

        foreach (var entryEvent in events)
        {
            if (entryEvent.EventType == CacheEntryEventType.Created && _cache.Remove(entryEvent.Key))
            {
                // Run consumer logic here - use another thread for heavy processing.
                Consume(entryEvent.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then we deploy this to every node with a single call:

```
var consumer = new CacheEventListener<Guid, string>(cache.Name);
var continuousQuery = new ContinuousQuery<Guid, string>(consumer);
cache.QueryContinuous(continuousQuery);
```

As a result, `OnEvent` is called once per entry on the primary node for that entry. So there is one consumer per Ignite node. We can increase effective number of consumers per node by offloading actual consumer logic to other threads, using `BlockingCollection` and so on.

And one last thing - we have to come up with a unique cache key for every new entry. Simplest thing is `Guid.NewGuid()`, but we can also use `AtomicSequence`.

Comment: Thanks Pavel. This exactly what we were doing but we felt like reinventing what is already available in Java. 1 use case of my question is not clear, we want to ensure that an item is processed only by 1 processor max at a time. do we have a suggestion or example on how to do this? this is a very common use case for queues where they deliver to one consumer at a time or broadcast to all consumers

Comment: Oh, `1 consumer` confused me. Can you please describe the use case in more detail? How many consumers would you like? Is it a classic producer-consumer scenario, and you would like to scale it to multiple machines?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Right now the case is typical Producer Consumer scenario where multiple producers (on multiple machines) insert items into a queue. Now there could be multiple consumers present again on multiple machines but only 1 consumer should process an item. E.g. there are P1,P2 producers they generate T1,T2,T3 and we have C1,C2,C3 consumers now T1 should be processed by ONLY 1 from C1,C2,C3 and so on for T2,T3 should also similarly be processed only once by 1 consumer

Comment: @RishabhJain I've updated the answer to address your concerns. With ContinuousQuery, you will have at least one consumer per node, and this consumer is only called for entries that are local to that node. It guarantees that every entry is processed once and only once.

Comment: FYI, actual Java implementation of `IgniteQueue` uses `IgniteCache.getAndRemove` in a loop on consumer side. The problem here is to know the key, and they use a very complicated logic to maintain the range of currently available keys. I believe that `ContinuousQuery` is a simpler solution for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I like the idea of using blocking queue. I approached the solution today by using cache locks. So basically the first consumer that gets the lock on the key gets to process the item. Remaining consumers skip it as they won't get lock on that particular key.  This way the item remains in the queue till it fails or retries are finished.